# Ansible. Dictionary selection by field value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Ansible question about dictionary selection by field value.

I would like something like:

```
{{ lookup('filetree', 'zabbix/') | grep('state', 'directory') }}
```

but for now, the only thing that came to mind

```
- debug:
    msg: "{%- set rv = [] -%}
          {%- for i in lookup('filetree', 'zabbix/') -%}
            {%- do rv.append(i) if i.state == 'directory' -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {{ rv }}"
tags:
  - test
```

I would like a more compact version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- name: nginx direcories
  file:
    path: "{{ nginx_dir }}/{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ lookup('filetree', 'nginx/', wantlist=True) | json_query('[?state==`directory`].path') }}"
  tags:
    - nginx_update_configs


- name: install nginx configs
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ nginx_dir }}/{{ item.path }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('filetree', 'nginx/', wantlist=True) | json_query('[?state!=`directory`]') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
  notify:
    - reload nginx
  tags:
    - nginx_update_configs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `selectattr` filter.  For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ lookup('filetree', '~/tmp')|
          selectattr('state', 'eq', 'directory')|list }}
```

See the [Jinja filter documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) for more information.